# MQTT over SSL with PAHO C

Tags: c, ssl, mqtt, iot, paho

I'm trying to figure out how paho works with SSL. 
I've tested a simple pub (without SSL) using mosquitto as broker (with default mosquitto.conf) and all works well. Now I've modified the code below (using the ADDRESS define instead of ADDRESSTEST) for testing SSL. I've used the certified provided by the section "[test](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c/tree/master/test/ssl)" of paho.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <MQTTClient.h>


#define ADDRESS     "ssl://localhost:18885"
#define ADDRESSTEST     "tcp://localhost:1883"
#define CLIENTID    "ExampleClientPub"
#define TOPIC       "MQTTExamples"
#define PAYLOAD     "Hello World!"
#define QOS         1
#define TIMEOUT     10000L


int main() {

MQTTClient client;

MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
MQTTClient_SSLOptions ssl_opts = MQTTClient_SSLOptions_initializer;;

MQTTClient_message pubmsg = MQTTClient_message_initializer;
MQTTClient_deliveryToken token;
int rc;

MQTTClient_create(&client, ADDRESS, CLIENTID,
    MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_DEFAULT, NULL);

conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
conn_opts.cleansession = 1;

conn_opts.ssl = &ssl_opts;
conn_opts.ssl->trustStore = "../../validpath/test-root-ca.crt";
conn_opts.ssl->keyStore = "../../validpath/client.pem";

conn_opts.serverURIcount = 0;
conn_opts.serverURIs = NULL;

if ((rc = MQTTClient_connect(client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

pubmsg.payload = PAYLOAD;
pubmsg.payloadlen = (int)strlen(PAYLOAD);
pubmsg.qos = QOS;
pubmsg.retained = 0;


MQTTClient_publishMessage(client, TOPIC, &pubmsg, &token);
printf("Waiting for up to %d seconds for publication of %s\n"
        "on topic %s for client with ClientID: %s\n",
        (int)(TIMEOUT/1000), PAYLOAD, TOPIC, CLIENTID);
rc = MQTTClient_waitForCompletion(client, token, TIMEOUT);
printf("Message with delivery token %d delivered\n", token);
MQTTClient_disconnect(client, 10000);
MQTTClient_destroy(&client);

return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when i run the software with this configuration, the MQTTClient_connect return me the code [MQTTCLIENT_WRONG_MQTT_VERSION](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTClient/html/_m_q_t_t_client_8h.html#ae9070d21de569f999a9575049cdd6da1). Mosquitto runs in localhost and I've modified the mosquitto.conf in this way:

```
# server authentication - no client authentication
listener 18885
cafile validpath/all-ca.crt
certfile validpath/server.crt
keyfile validpath/server.key
require_certificate false
#tls_version tlsv1
```

Comment: So what is your 'bridge_protocol_version' line set to in your mosquitto.conf?  it defaults to 'mqttv311', which should work with your Paho library.  For grins, try setting it to 'mqttv11' and see what happens.  Your error seems more focused on the Mosquitto Broker settings than anything TLS related.

Comment: Also, if you have control over the broker you should be able to get diagnostics from it, eg. with mosquitto -v "1585659783: New connection from 192.9.200.15 on port 1883.
1585659783: Invalid protocol version 5 in CONNECT from 192.9.200.15."

Comment: @JDAllen This shouldn't be hitting the bridge code at all, that settings is for outbound bridge connections from the broker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs when you compile with -lpaho-mqtt3c, instead of -lpaho-mqtt3cs (that enable SSL). Now it works properly!